# Holomorphic function: How to show that a specific function is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $p(z_1,z_2,...,z_n)$ is a complex n-varibles polynomial. The function $p$ will be holomorphic if and only if its real and imaginary part are differentiable function in the real sense and if its real and imaginary part satisfy the Cauchy Reamann equation.
How can i see that a polynmial satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equation?

Comment: by using polar coordinates?

Comment: How is this any different from showing a polynomial in a single variable satisfies the Cauchy Riemann equations?